# Multiple pages, single controller, how to set it up in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, view

I have a 'home' controller which deals with the basic Home, About, Courses, Contact pages.  There are multiple courses available, each with their own page and I would like to know the best method for referencing these pages.  I could just create them as additional pages and add an actionresult to the home controller for each page.  So the url for a course would be home/course1.  Presumably there is a much better method than this though.

Ideally I'd like to have the individual course pages in a separate folder within the view folder and their url to be /home/courses/course1.  Can anyone explain the best method using MVC for organising these pages?

Comment: What framework or language are you using!

Comment: What 'better' method are you expecting?

Comment: I am using asp.net MVC 5, I was hoping for something neater than simply listing all of the individual pages in the controller.  For example, some way to mark the Courses action in the controller so that it responded to links for each individual page without listing them all as their own separate action?

Comment: It sounds like you are not using a database, just static .cshtml pages (one for each course), is that right? If so, then there is little you can do except write manual controller code for every .cshtml page, because MVC is not going to 'see' or 'discover' those by itself. The other approach - used by just about any website, and for good reasons - is to use a database with a `Course` table, and create code and pages to maintain and show the contents of that table.

Answer (score 0):

So it goes like this : There will be a single page for all the courses and all the course pages will be partial views now there will be a div on the main page and whenever user clicks one of the course name.. it will fire an ajax request and it returns the required partial and populate the div with the returned content. You can give a common class to all the links of Courses, just like this :

.`<a class="couseTrigger" data-source="@Url.Action("Name of Partialview action,"
     name of controller")">
    ------ Script -----
    $('.couseTrigger').click(function(){
        var _this = $(this);
        var url = _this.data('source');
        --then make the ajax request to this url pvariable and retrun the     partial view.
    });`

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple courser avoid creating multiple webpages for those courses. Rather have the content of each course stored in a database and retrieve specific course content by some parameter and bind it to the webpage. Creating webpage for each course is not feasible. Suppose you have 100 courses are u gonna create 100 webpages ?